# Android webpage interactivity

Tags: android, web

Lets say there are two android devices and a webpage.

On each of those devices there is a button being clicked and the webpage shows the accumulated clicks.

What makes this possible?
Are the android devices sending that data to a sql database and that counter is reading what currently is in that database?
Or can the device really send the information into the page?

Comment: Why the "two android devices"?

Comment: It could be any number of devices.

Comment: Are you asking how Android devices communicate with web services? How is it relevant what OS the devices accessing a website run?

Comment: It could be any mobile device.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. Do you want to know how to make a website with a persistent counter? Do you want to know how to interact with a website in an android client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device can communicate data to the server or to the client side code. You can then have to decide what to do with the data. If you send it to the client side code then it would only update on one device, whereas sending it to the server would allow one click counter across every device.

Changing the page on the server side would add caching problems. So you probably want a data file instead, just a json or something that the server overwrites every time it receives another click.

This isn't very fast though and causes synchronisation issues between the users. For starters for a standard html page the client code is in charge of the calls to the server, so we would have to check the server periodically to see if the value has changed (say every 5 seconds).

A faster alternative would be to use a web socket. The client would keep a connection open to the server and listen for updates from the server, removing the need for our periodic check. Additionally the socket can be used to send clicks to the server and the server can keep the value in its memory removing the need for file writes.

Node.js can be downloaded from http://nodejs.org and this is the plug in I use for web sockets https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node.

So here is some server side code for a simple web socket server that parrots messages from 1 user to all users, including the user who sent it.

```
var connections = [];
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    // process HTTP request. Since we're writing just WebSockets server
    // we don't have to implement anything.
});
server.listen(1337, function() { });

// create the server
wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

// WebSocket server
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {

    //got a new user requesting a connection, so lets accept and store them
    var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    connections.push(connection);

    connection.on('message', function(message) { //inbound message
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            // process WebSocket message
            send(message.utf8Data); //bounce to everyone else
            console.log(message);
        }
    });
});

setInterval(function(){console.log(connections.length +" :users");},5000);
//every 5 seconds, tell us how many users we have

function send(message){
    var i = connections.length;
    while(i--)
        connections[i].send(message);
    //send the message to all users
}
```

Example client side

```
<html><head><script>
var connection, connIsActive = false;
    // if user is running mozilla then use it's built-in WebSocket
    window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;

    connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:1337');

    connection.onopen = function () {
        // connection is opened and ready to use
        connIsActive = true;
        console.log('Connection loaded');
    };

    connection.onerror = function (error) {
        // an error occurred when sending/receiving data
        connIsActive = false
        console.log('error');
    };

    connection.onmessage = function (message) {
        // handle incoming message
        console.log(message.data);

    };
function send(message){
    if(connIsActive)connection.send(message);
}
</script></head></html>
```

Save the first snippet as "myserver.js" (or similar) and start it up in node via command line. Save the second snippet as a "client.html" and open it on 2 devices, or just 2 browser instances. Theres no interface on the client but you can send and receive messages from the debug console using `send("message string")`

Provided you can wrap your head around my snippets, modifying it to work like your example should prove fairly easy!

Comment: Node.js looks like the way to go.

Comment: What demo would you suggest?

Comment: I'll post up the web sockets test code I wrote when I first started node, it's basic kinda send and log stuff but it should get you started. You will need to install node and a suitable web socket plug in for it.

Comment: Thank you brother! I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Glad to be able to help! If you've managed to get this working I'd suggest that you could expand the `http.createServer(function()...` to serve the html page for you as well. Also note the ip address on the html snippet is for localhost, and hence the html will only work if its on the same device as what your running node on! Change it the the local ip of the node server to access it from anywhere on your network.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are trying to do, you need to learn socket programming for android.

In order to use two device(clients) you also need to learn port forwarding for servers.

To begin try this [tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/).